# Upload image question, How to get raw format of image from buffer and reset the metadata?

Tags: javascript, image, sharp

I try to upload image by post request with image file and Content-Type "image/jpeg"

the raw image data store in event.body the format like:

```
��������^w��Rs:禽6�zy
```

I try to use sharp lib to resize the image but fail as:

```
const bodybuffer = Buffer.from(event.body!);
var buffer = sharp(bodybuffer).metadata(resize(width).toBuffer();
```

The error is:

```
[Error: Input buffer contains unsupported image format]
```

I do not know where to initialize the image with metadata format = "jpeg".

Comment: `Buffer.from(event.body!);` here, `event.body!` is just a boolean value. The issue is with your  `bodybuffer` value before entering sharp. Also what is `resiz(width)` ? it doesn't seem to accept an image input, just the `width` ?

Comment: The event.body type is string | undefined. I use '!' is because Buffer.from(string), the function only accepts string, So I want to change the event.body to string.

Comment: Sorry I was confused I thought it was `!event.body`

Comment: Is that the whole string you got? It's very short for an image

Comment: No, just sample string. the whole string is very long, so I just give the sample

Comment: Can you try writing the buffer to a file, to make sure it's valid?

Comment: I can not do that, because I use the serverless framework. On serverless I try to write to s3 bucket, but get error: ```      const destparams = {
          Bucket: dstBucket,
          Key: dstKey,
          Body: bodybuffer,
          ContentType: "image/jpg"
      };

      const putResult = await mys3.putObject(destparams).promise();```

But get error:

[XMLParserError]: Non-whitespace before first tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216375/discussion-between-thammada-ts-and-user504909).